# I would like a moderator to merge my accounts after verification

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am registered as [Ben Welborn](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/14191/ben-welborn) but somehow I previously answered a question as unregistered user [Ben Welborn](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/14190/ben-welborn). Can a moderator please merge my accounts after verification?

Comment: Surely two Welborn's is better than one? :)

Answer (score 7):

Moderators can't merge accounts; that has to be handled by Stack Exchange staff, and they generally prefer that you contact them directly.

I left a comment on your post with directions to the [relevant page in the help center](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and a pointer to the "[contact us](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/contact)" link at the bottom of every page on the site which will take you to a form to fill out. It may take a few days for them to process the request, depending on how busy they are, but neither account is going anywhere and it will happen when they get around to it.